# Run a process just after shell is executed windows 7

Tags: windows-7, registry

I have a situation where I need to hide the taskbar and start button from my desktop in windows 7
I already have a code written to do so.
The issue is that I need to run it just the moment windows finishes loading the explorer.exe from shell.
I tried giving path of my exe after explorer.exe in shell(in registry) using the comma but it does not run explorer rather it opens my computer on startup.
If I put my exe in the startup lineup then the issue is that the taskbar is visible for 4-5 seconds and then it hides.
I want the taskbar to be not visible at all on logon

Comment: Try to set auto hide flag of taskbar to ON ..I did this with registry but now i forgot the key name....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add your application to the Run key in the registry?
It should run right after logon. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314866